# What is required to run a job scheduler in mysql?

Tags: mysql, job-scheduling

I need a job scheduler to run at regular intervals, for instance every 5 hours. Which job scheduler is a good idea or are there any other techniques to run an event, for e.g. code. Would it require and additional, external software requirements.

My machine has Windows XP and working on the PHP with MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

use mysql events

from [this](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-events.html)

```
mysql> use test;
Database changed
mysql> create table test.t (s1 timestamp);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

14mysql> create event e on schedule every 5 hour do
       insert into test.t values (current_timestamp);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> set global event_scheduler = 1;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: create event e on schedule every 5 hour do
       insert into test.t values (current_timestamp);
It will work after every 5hours.... But I want after Every 5 days or after every 3 months..? than what to do?

Comment: @Gnanendra create event e on schedule at timestamp 'your time'

Answer (score 0):

[SQLyog's](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) Job Agent (SJA) is the powerful tool which includes Scheduling Database Synchronization, Schema Synchronization, Import External Data, Scheduled Back-ups, SQL scheduler & Reporting Tool(to Schedule queries). It is very easy and intuitive to use. You can try it to schedule almost all kinds of MySQL jobs.

[image]

Hope it helps and solves your purpose...