# Equivalent in MySQL to MS SQL Jobs?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration, jobs, job-scheduling

Is there a MySQL equivalent to the MS SQL Server jobs and job scheduling?  Or is that kind of thing considered an application-layer thing in the MySQL world?

Comment: I would actually consider it an operating system thing (e.g. `cron`)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what are required to run job scheduler in mysql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700522/what-are-required-to-run-job-scheduler-in-mysql)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you looking for the [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-overview.html)?

> When you create an event, you are creating a named database object
>   containing one or more SQL statements to be executed at one or more
>   regular intervals, beginning and ending at a specific date and time.