# Execute a DB query every 30 mins in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, exadata

As part of my job I have to periodically check for failed items in the database. I have the query with me. Instead of manually executing the query every now and then I want to execute it in a predefined interval automatically and capture those items in an excel sheet or trigger a mail to certain recipients.
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Refer this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700522/what-is-required-to-run-a-job-scheduler-in-mysql

Comment: you wont be able to get MySQL to write to an excel sheet. 
I believe Microsoft Flow May be able to do this as it has a MySQL connector. Otherwise a scripting language such as python script set to run on a 30min interval would definitely work. Are you familiar with any scripting languages?

Comment: What are 'failed items'? There may be some way in SQL of enforcing they don't happen.

Comment: Make a cron job / scheduled task in your server.

Comment: I am not familiar with python but will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

```
*/30 * * * * ("PUT your query here")
```

You Can do this by using cronjob